# How can I map numeric values to the fill attribute of a map in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggvis

I am using the following code to draw a map in ggvis

First I download the json file with the coordinates

```
us <- readOGR("http://eric.clst.org/wupl/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_20m.json", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

Then I fortify the dataset

```
map <- ggplot2::fortify(us)
```

And I create a dataset of the values that I want to represent in the map, standardized from 0 to 1:

```
value <- data_frame(stateName=us$NAME, value=seq(1:52)/52)
```

Lastly, I (succesfully) draw my map:

```
tbl_df(map)%>%
  filter(long>-130 & long<0) %>% 
  filter(lat>20) %>% 
  ggvis(~long, ~lat) %>%
  group_by(group, id) %>%
  layer_paths(strokeOpacity:=0.5, stroke:="#7f7f7f", fill:="#cc0000") %>%
  scale_numeric("y", domain=c(24,50)) %>% 
  scale_numeric("x", domain=c(-126,-72)) %>% 
  hide_legend("fill") %>%
  hide_axis("x") %>% 
  hide_axis("y") %>%
  set_options(width=400, height=600, keep_aspect=TRUE)
```

However, because the all process is a bit black-boxy to me, I don't know how to map the values from the dataset `value` to the ggvis map efficiently. I would like to use a color gradient on the fill attribute, but even playing with the transparency would be ok.

I guess I should tell to `fortify()` to keep the `us$NAME`, but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that:

```
us@data$id = rownames(us@data)
us_class = fortify(us, region="id")
us.df = join(us_class, us@data, by="id")
value <- data_frame(NAME=us$NAME, value=seq(1:52)/52)
us.df <- join(us.df, value)

tbl_df(us.df)%>%
  filter(long>-130 & long<0) %>% 
  filter(lat>20) %>% 
  ggvis(~long, ~lat) %>%
  group_by(group, id) %>%
  layer_paths(strokeOpacity:=0.5, stroke:="#7f7f7f", fill:="#cc0000") %>%
  scale_numeric("y", domain=c(24,50)) %>% 
  scale_numeric("x", domain=c(-126,-72)) %>% 
  hide_legend("fill") %>%
  hide_axis("x") %>% 
  hide_axis("y") %>%
  set_options(width=400, height=600, keep_aspect=TRUE) %>%
  layer_paths(fill= ~value)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The second line retrieves me this error `Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE`. Do you know what may cause the prolem? Also, I would expect the colors to be different, because I am mapping to the color a continuous variable without duplicates. Why this is not the case?

Comment: here is my session Info: maptools_0.8-36 plyr_1.8.3      rgeos_0.3-11    rgdal_1.0-4     sp_1.2-2        ggplot2_2.1.0   ggvis_0.4.2     dplyr_0.4.3

Comment: Thanks a lot! The error was probably due to a few outdated packages.